# Update devise user attributes as nested attributes from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, updates

I have user model, and each user `has_one` profile model. I want to update profile model. But there just two attributes in User model (first_name, and last_name). So I used `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

When I call update action, I receive the following errors on profile model:

1. email can't be blank
2. password can't be blank

The following my code:

**User Model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :confirmable
   has_one :profile
end
```

**Profile Model:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

**Profile controller - update action**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
   def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:current_city_id, :current_country_id, :google_plus_page_url, :linkedin_page_url, :facebook_page_url, :skype_id, :user_attributes => [:first_name, :last_name])
  end
  def update
     @profile = Profile.find_by_id(params[:profile_id])
     respond_to do |format|
       if @profile.update(profile_params)
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
       else
          format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
  end
end
```

So, How can I update profile with user's nested attributes without email & password (In Profile Controller Not in devise controller) ??

Answer (score 1):

> When I call update action, I receive the following errors on profile
>   model:
>
> - email can't be blank
> - password can't be blank

Looks like the devise validation happen.

Remove `:validatable` from the use model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :confirmable
   has_one :profile
end
```

Or change this validation to something smarter, say `on: :create` only.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :confirmable
   has_one :profile
   validates :email, presence: true, email: true, on: :create
   validates :password, presence: true, on: :create
end
```

Comment: for implementation of this answer  `validates_format_of   :email, with: Devise::email_regexp, allow_blank: true`

Answer (score 0):

I believe `accepts_attributes_for` should be on the `User` model instead of the `Profile` model.

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
    :confirmable
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

Profile model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For new searchers, encountered this today. After hours of searching for nothing and failing, what I did was I tried to add the `id` as a `hidden_field` of the nested devise model fields. It fixed my problem.

ex:

```
<%= form.fields_for :users do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
  <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
<% end %>
```

No need to update or override the devise validations.

Strange. If you don't add the devise model `id` in the nested fields the update would treat the action for the nested model as a `create` action, causing devise to ask for the `email` and `password` fields.

Upsetting. No sign of the create action in the rails logs. If only there was a sign that the action went on to `create`, would have fixed this early.

Thanks.